# Carousel issue - Disappears from screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hi I have just started using the Bootstrap Carousel on my website. Now i am no great user of HTML or CSS as I am just a beginner ... So here is the webpage in question http://www.tightlinesuk.com ... now as you can see the Carousel loads fine then slides up and disappears, never to be seen again.

The theme I am using is a RapidWeaver Theme, Media by ThemeFlood. I am using the inbuilt snippet supplied with the theme and I have only changed the bits required i.e. Description and Photo Src path.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="%pathto(scripts/bootstrap.min.js)%"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 5000
})
});
</script>

<p>Welcome to Tight Lines UK. Tight Lines offers everything an angler needs. We offer competitively priced products from manufacturers all over the country. We are slowly adding more and more suppliers to our portfolio. We supply everything from Bait to Bivvies and everything in between. And if we haven't got it on the website it doesn't mean we can't get it for you, so drop us a line or give us a call and we will see what we can do .... TIGHT LINES</p>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
<img src="http://fishcatcheruk.co.uk/img/common/IMAGES/Carp.jpg" alt="Banner 1" style="width:100%;">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>Carp and Specimen Fishing</h4>
<p>In our Carp & Specimen section you will find everything you need from Boilie Stops to Bivvies. So drop in and have a look ..... TIGHT LINES</p>
</div><!--/carousel-caption-->
</div><!--/item-->

<div class="item">
<img src="http://fishcatcheruk.co.uk/img/common/IMAGES/Coarse.jpg" alt="Banner 2" style="width:100%;">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>Coarse Fishing</h4>
<p>In our Coarse fishing section you will find all your Coarse Fishing needs ..... TIGHT LINES</p>
</div><!--/carousel-caption-->
</div><!--/item-->

<div class="item">
<img src="http://fishcatcheruk.co.uk/img/common/IMAGES/Game.jpg" alt="Banner 3" style="width:100%;">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>Game Fishing</h4>
<p>Our Game Fishing section is currently under construction but will be open soon.</p>
</div>
</div><!--/carousel-caption-->
</div><!--/item-->

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

Now this code works perfect when you view in preview on RapidWeaver? Please tell me what I am doing wrong :) Thanks

Oh I am using RW 4.4.2 and Stacks 1

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching, trying and thinking I'm crazy, for me the solution was just to replace **bootstrap.min.js** with the newer version.